# Laravel 5.5 native multiauth with multiple model relation

Tags: laravel-5.5

I want to use Laravel native multi-auth for many types of user like students, schools, and admins.

I have 5 tables for this like:

- user_types: stores types of users
- users: stores login credentials
- admins: stores other details for admins
- students: stores other details for students
- schools: stores other details for schools

I am struggling a long time for this. Can anyone give me the idea, how to acheive this? Thanks in advance.

The difference is that I am storing email/passwords for all users in the "user" table and other information in their respective tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create multi auth in Laravel 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41843804/how-to-create-multi-auth-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: Hi @ImAtWar, Thanks for you for your response. The difference is that I am storing email/passwords for all users in the "user" table and other information in their respective tables. So, when try to log in, I get "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `admins` where `email` is null limit 1)" error, since email and password is stored in users  table.

Comment: You should store all your user types in a single users table and then create  different roles (users, admins, students, schools etc) in a roles table. Use a pivot table to assign relation between user and roles (user_roles). Once you acheive this relation you can create different middleware to check for the roles and access autorization. See Detailed turorial here https://www.5balloons.info/user-role-based-authentication-and-access-control-in-laravel/

Comment: Geat @Tushar, I was looking for exactly same. Thank you.

Comment: @bhattraideb ok, I am converting my comment into an answer, so you can accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You should store all your user types in a single users table and then create different roles (users, admins, students, schools etc) in a roles table. Use a pivot table to assign relation between user and roles (user_roles).

Once you acheive this relation you can create different middleware to check for the roles and access autorization. See Detailed turorial here

https://www.5balloons.info/user-role-based-authentication-and-access-control-in-laravel/

Comment: I followed your steps, but for every user, it goes to default home view after logged in. How to handle routing? Like when logged in as admin, it should go to admin dashboard and so on for other users. Also, while logged out from school, it should redirect to school login view.

Comment: It depends on which Controller section you are trying to access. Let's say you have an admin section yourapp.com/admin . If you configure AdminController with correct middleware when user tries to access admin home page he should first see a login page and if he has the access once he logins he should be able to see the login page.

Comment: My middleware "CheckRole" not being called. I am trying to check role and redirect for admin to the admin dashboard from this middleware. Here is my middleware: public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    { var_dump((Auth::User())); die;
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
            abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }